# Count of Open Child Items for Parent Item in Azure DevOps

Tags: azure-devops

We are using DevOps to track requirements and we have child tasks for each of the requirements - FS, TS, DEV, TUT, FUT, and UAT as shown in the image below -

[image: ADO Requirement]

We want to write a query to find the number of open child tasks, i.e. 1 in the below case. This will help us identify where the CR is at with respect to tasks.